# How to add only right border to expander

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to avoid border all around expander contents. i have a expander in my left side menu panel. I just want a border at the end of panel.

```
  <Expander FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  BorderBrush="LightGray" Margin="0,5"  ExpandDirection="Right" IsExpanded="True">
```

Putting 'BorderBrush="LightGray"' gives border all around expander contents.

Comment: BorderThickness is what u r looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled by several methods. Check if below option suits your need.

1. Set your "Borderthickness" property of the expander control as below.

```html
  <Expander FlowDirection="RightToLeft" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"  BorderBrush="LightGray" Margin="0,5"  ExpandDirection="Right" IsExpanded="True">
```